# Qt: How to capture mouse movement in QVideoWidget?

Tags: qt, pyside, pyside6, qt6

I tried this but this doesn't track the mouse movement unless a button is pressed:

```py
from PySide6 import QtWidgets as qtw
from PySide6 import QtMultimediaWidgets as qtmw


app = qtw.QApplication()

vw = qtmw.QVideoWidget()
vw.setMouseTracking(True)
vw.mouseMoveEvent = lambda *x: print(1)
vw.show()

app.exec()
```

On other widgets, I would `setMouseTracking(True)` for the `.viewport()`, but it doesn't look like `QVideoWidget` has a viewport.

Comment: I don't have PySide6 installed but the code shown works just fine for me with PySide2, Qt 5.15.2, Python 3.10.2 on MacOS 10.13.6.

Comment: @G.M. oh, you're right, it works on PySide2 for me too. How strange.

Comment: In Qt6, a private internal class is used for rendering the video, so add `vw.children()[0].setMouseTracking(True)`.

Comment: @ekhumoro yeah, it worked. Thank you. Though, can I ask how you got that information?

Comment: There are other widgets that have a similar structure (e.g. `QWebEngineView`), so it was partly an educated guess. And you can always look at the source code.